# FileUploadInterceptor didn't intercept the large file

Tags: struts2

After a large file is uploaded, I only get the warning message in my console but it didn't stop me, the message is as follow:

> WARN FileUploadInterceptor:56 - The file is to large to be uploaded:
>   _7fa0eae6b3a9b769f938dd52c0fde541_imgThumb "170587_10150170888553504_2474786_o.jpg"
>   "upload__24f6477e_140de810828__8000_00000008.tmp" 415411

Here is my Struts.xml setting:

```
<constant name="struts.multipart.maxSize" value="20480000" />
...

<package name="Image" extends="json-default,struts-default,my-default">
    ...
    <action name="saveImage" class="example.Test" method="saveImg"> 
        <interceptor-ref name="defaultStack"></interceptor-ref>
        <interceptor-ref name="exception"/>
        <interceptor-ref name="fileUpload">
            <param name="maximumSize">1</param>
            <param name="allowedTypes">image/tiff,image/jpeg</param>
        </interceptor-ref>
        <interceptor-ref name="params" />
        <interceptor-ref name="validation" />
        <interceptor-ref name="json">
            <param name="contentType">application/json</param>
        </interceptor-ref>
        <result name="success" type="json">
            <param name="root">save</param>
        </result>
        <result name="error" type="json">
            <param name="root">save</param>
        </result>
        <result name="invalid.token">/WEB-INF/jsp/invalidToken.jsp</result>
    </action>
```

Any help would be appreciated!

Comment: use this value for constant: <constant name="struts.multipart.maxSize" value="1024000000" />

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You are including the File Upload Interceptor twice, because it is already present in the Default Stack.

[The Default Stack is defined as:](http://struts.apache.org/release/2.3.x/docs/interceptors.html)

```
<!-- A complete stack with all the common interceptors in place.
         Generally, this stack should be the one you use, though it
         may do more than you need. Also, the ordering can be
         switched around (ex: if you wish to have your servlet-related
         objects applied before prepare() is called, you'd need to move
         servletConfig interceptor up.

         This stack also excludes from the normal validation and workflow
         the method names input, back, and cancel. These typically are
         associated with requests that should not be validated.
-->

<interceptor-stack name="defaultStack">
    <interceptor-ref name="exception"/>
    <interceptor-ref name="alias"/>
    <interceptor-ref name="servletConfig"/>
    <interceptor-ref name="i18n"/>
    <interceptor-ref name="prepare"/>
    <interceptor-ref name="chain"/>
    <interceptor-ref name="scopedModelDriven"/>
    <interceptor-ref name="modelDriven"/>
    <interceptor-ref name="fileUpload"/>
    <interceptor-ref name="checkbox"/>
    <interceptor-ref name="multiselect"/>
    <interceptor-ref name="staticParams"/>
    <interceptor-ref name="actionMappingParams"/>
    <interceptor-ref name="params">
        <param name="excludeParams">dojo\..*,^struts\..*,^session\..*,^request\..*,^application\..*,^servlet(Request|Response)\..*,parameters\...*</param>
    </interceptor-ref>
    <interceptor-ref name="conversionError"/>
    <interceptor-ref name="validation">
        <param name="excludeMethods">input,back,cancel,browse</param>
    </interceptor-ref>
    <interceptor-ref name="workflow">
        <param name="excludeMethods">input,back,cancel,browse</param>
    </interceptor-ref>
    <interceptor-ref name="debugging"/>
</interceptor-stack>
```

Then what you are actually defining for your Action is

```
<action name="saveImage" class="example.Test" method="saveImg">     

    <!-- DEFAULT STACK IMPORT EXPLODED -->
    <interceptor-ref name="exception"/>
    <interceptor-ref name="alias"/>
    <interceptor-ref name="servletConfig"/>
    <interceptor-ref name="i18n"/>
    <interceptor-ref name="prepare"/>
    <interceptor-ref name="chain"/>
    <interceptor-ref name="scopedModelDriven"/>
    <interceptor-ref name="modelDriven"/>
    <interceptor-ref name="fileUpload"/>
    <interceptor-ref name="checkbox"/>
    <interceptor-ref name="multiselect"/>
    <interceptor-ref name="staticParams"/>
    <interceptor-ref name="actionMappingParams"/>
    <interceptor-ref name="params">
        <param name="excludeParams">dojo\..*,^struts\..*,^session\..*,^request\..*,^application\..*,^servlet(Request|Response)\..*,parameters\...*</param>
    </interceptor-ref>
    <interceptor-ref name="conversionError"/>
    <interceptor-ref name="validation">
        <param name="excludeMethods">input,back,cancel,browse</param>
    </interceptor-ref>
    <interceptor-ref name="workflow">
        <param name="excludeMethods">input,back,cancel,browse</param>
    </interceptor-ref>
    <interceptor-ref name="debugging"/>

    <!-- YOUR ADDITIONAL SETTINGS -->
    <interceptor-ref name="exception"/>
    <interceptor-ref name="fileUpload">
        <param name="maximumSize">1</param>
        <param name="allowedTypes">image/tiff,image/jpeg</param>
    </interceptor-ref>
    <interceptor-ref name="params" />
    <interceptor-ref name="validation" />
    <interceptor-ref name="json">
        <param name="contentType">application/json</param>
    </interceptor-ref>
    <result name="success" type="json">
        <param name="root">save</param>
    </result>
    <result name="error" type="json">
        <param name="root">save</param>
    </result>
    <result name="invalid.token">/WEB-INF/jsp/invalidToken.jsp</result>
</action>
```

As you can see, many Interceptors are defined twice. Simply create an custom Interceptor Stack, and use it in all the Actions you need, or specify the Interceptors manually without including the Default Stack.

Something like

```
    <interceptor-ref name="exception"/>
    <interceptor-ref name="alias"/>
    <interceptor-ref name="servletConfig"/>
    <interceptor-ref name="i18n"/>
    <interceptor-ref name="prepare"/>
    <interceptor-ref name="chain"/>
    <interceptor-ref name="scopedModelDriven"/>
    <interceptor-ref name="modelDriven"/>
    <interceptor-ref name="fileUpload">
        <param name="maximumSize">1</param>
        <param name="allowedTypes">image/tiff,image/jpeg</param>
    </interceptor-ref>
    <interceptor-ref name="checkbox"/>
    <interceptor-ref name="multiselect"/>
    <interceptor-ref name="staticParams"/>
    <interceptor-ref name="actionMappingParams"/>
    <interceptor-ref name="params">
        <param name="excludeParams">dojo\..*,^struts\..*,^session\..*,^request\..*,^application\..*,^servlet(Request|Response)\..*,parameters\...*</param>
    </interceptor-ref>
    <interceptor-ref name="conversionError"/>
    <interceptor-ref name="validation">
        <param name="excludeMethods">input,back,cancel,browse</param>
    </interceptor-ref>
    <interceptor-ref name="workflow">
        <param name="excludeMethods">input,back,cancel,browse</param>
    </interceptor-ref>
    <interceptor-ref name="debugging"/>
    <interceptor-ref name="json">
        <param name="contentType">application/json</param>
    </interceptor-ref>
```

Comment: Hi Andrea, thanks for your reply! I was wondering if the second-include can override the first-include? In your answer, I learn that struts will ignore the duplicated including-interceptor after the first one is included.

Comment: No, it should pass two times in the Interceptor. But you've defined the same Interceptor twice with two different settings, and I don't know exactly what would happen in this case. It's simpler to fix the situation and try with a single Interceptor with the right settings. P.S: remember that 1 means 1 byte :)